# Rapidly redrawing Tkinter window - What is a faster way?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a microenvironmental simulator in Python, and so far I have a fractal map generator and a simple collision-detecting class of moving 'entities'.  The entities worked fine when the canvas was sparse, but now that it has to redraw the map with each update, it runs slowly.  I am using create_rectangle's to visualize the entity matrix on top of the map matrix (it's called 'tiles').

I have tried using pygame and a few other modules, but I can't get them to work with any version of python (even older and 32-bit versions), I think this is because I am running Windows 7 64-bit, they do not seem compatible.

Anyway, is there any way to more quickly visualize these two matrices so that I can get higher FPS?

Thank you very much, here is my code (you can move the white entity with arrow keys!!!):

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *
from time import *

root = Tk()

w = Canvas(root, width = 640, height=640)
w.pack()

entities = []
running = True

## Size of squares, in pixels
size = 5

## Make tiles a 128x128 array
tiles = []
for i in range(128):
    tiles.append(128*[0])


## IMPORTANT: all entities must have .x and .y attributes!

class Entity:

    def __init__(self):
        self.setup()
        entities.append(self)

    def setup(self, x=0,y=0, name='Undefined', color='pink'):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def checkCollsn(self, try_x , try_y):
        for i in entities:
            if i is not self and try_x == i.x and try_y == i.y:
                print i.name, 'is in the way of', self.name, '!'
                return False
        else:
            ## print 'All clear!'
            return True


    def maintain(self):

        for i in entities:
            if i is not self:
                ## Detect anything in immediate proximity:
                dx = abs(i.x - self.x)
                dy = abs(i.y - self.y)
                if (dx == 1 or dx == 0) and (dy == 1 or dy== 0):
                    print self.name, 'has detected', i.name
                    ## TODO: Then what?

        ## TODO: Add other 'maintainance checks' here.


class Mobile(Entity):  ## Mobile is a subclass of Entity, which can move!  
    def up(self):
        if self.y < 1:
            print 'Upper bound!'
        else:
            if self.checkCollsn(self.x, self.y-1):
                self.y -= 1

    def down(self):
        if self.y > 127:
            print 'Lower bound!'
        else:
            if self.checkCollsn(self.x, self.y+1):
                self.y += 1

    def left(self):
        if self.x < 1:
            print 'Leftmost bound!'
        else:
            if self.checkCollsn(self.x-1, self.y):
                self.x -= 1

    def right(self):
        if self.x > 127:
            print 'Rightmost bound!'
        else:
            if self.checkCollsn(self.x+1, self.y):
                self.x += 1


def fractalGen(iterations=5, chanceWater=0.5):
    for i in range(iterations):
        if i == 0:
            ## Generate random 16x16 blocks
            blockNo = 8
            blockLen = 16
            randomize = True
            fractalize = False
        else:
            randomize = False
            fractalize = True

        if i == 1:
            blockNo = 16
            blockLen = 8

        if i == 2:
            blockNo = 32
            blockLen = 4

        if i == 3:
            blockNo = 64
            blockLen = 2

        if i == 4:
            blockNo = 128
            blockLen = 1

        if i > 4:
            print 'Excessive i value! Was', i

        for yBlock in range(blockNo):
            ## If it stays red, something's screwy!
            blockVal = 0

            for xBlock in range(blockNo):
                if randomize:
                    ## print 'i:',i,'Randomizing.'
                    r = random()
                    if r <= chanceWater:
                        blockVal = 4
                    else: blockVal = 3

                if fractalize:
                    land = 0
                    water = 0
                    ## First, assess surrounding % water of all valid surrounding blocks.
                    ## Remember, blocks are now higher res than previous iteration!


                    xRange = [0]  ## This paragraph makes sure we're staying within
                    yRange = [0]  ## the range of the matrix.

                    if xBlock != 0:
                        xRange.append(-1)
                    if xBlock != blockNo-1:
                        xRange.append(1)

                    if yBlock != 0:
                        yRange.append(-1)
                    if yBlock != blockNo-1:
                        yRange.append(1)                    


                    for ySign in yRange:
                        yCheck = (yBlock+ySign)*blockLen
                        for xSign in xRange:
                            xCheck = (xBlock+xSign)*blockLen
                            if xSign ==0 and ySign == 0:
                                selfVal = tiles[yCheck][xCheck]
                                ## print 'Self is', selfVal
                            else:
                                if tiles[yCheck][xCheck] == 4:
                                    ## print 'Water at', xCheck, yCheck
                                    water += 1
                                if tiles[yCheck][xCheck] == 3:
                                    land += 1
                                    ## print 'Land at', xCheck, yCheck
                    percentWater = water/float(land+water)
                    ##print percentWater
                    if selfVal == 4: #If self is water, oppSurr is % land
                        oppSurr = 1 - percentWater
                    if selfVal == 3: #If self is land, oppSurr is % water
                        oppSurr = percentWater

                    r = randint(0,25)/100.0
                    ##print oppSurr, r, oppSurr + r

                    if oppSurr + r >= 0.625:
                    ## If surroundings + random > 50%, switch self type!
                        if selfVal == 4:
                            blockVal = 3
                            ## print 'To land'
                        elif selfVal == 3:
                            blockVal = 4
                            ## print 'To water'
                    ## else: print 'Not switched, remains', selfVal
                    else: blockVal = selfVal


                    ## NB: Must assign blockVal in all cases, otherwise
                    ## you get the last value of blockVal carried over!

                for y in range(yBlock*blockLen,(yBlock+1)*blockLen):
                    for x in range(xBlock*blockLen,(xBlock+1)*blockLen):
                        tiles[y][x] = blockVal


def drawWorld():

    w.delete(ALL)

    x=0
    y=0

    for i in tiles:
        for j in i:
            color = 'gray'
            if j == 0: tColor = 'red'
            if j == 1: tColor = 'orange'
            if j == 2: tColor = 'yellow'
            if j == 3: tColor = 'green'
            if j == 4: tColor = 'blue'
            if j == 5: tColor = 'purple'

            w.create_rectangle(x,y,x+size,y+size,fill=tColor)
            x += size
        x = 0
        y += size

    for i in entities:
        w.create_rectangle(i.x*size, i.y*size, i.x*size+size, i.y*size+size, fill=i.color)


    w.update()


fractalGen(5,.4)
drawWorld()

def keyPress(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        p.up()

    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        p.down()

    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        p.left()

    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        p.right()


def moveRand(ent):
    cmd = randint(0,3) 
    if cmd == 0: ent.up()
    if cmd == 1: ent.down()
    if cmd == 2: ent.left()
    if cmd == 3: ent.right()

## Player:
p = Mobile()
p.setup(0,5,'Man', 'white')

## Boulder:
b = Entity()
b.setup(10,15,'Boulder','black')

## Flower:
f = Entity()
f.setup(5,5,'Flower', 'red')

## Elf:
elf = Mobile()
elf.setup(10,10,'Elf','green')

interval = 0.2

while running:
        moveRand(elf)
        root.bind_all('<Key>', keyPress)

        for i in entities:
            i.maintain()

        drawWorld()
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things could probably be done to improve the FPS of your code:

1. Get rid of the w.update() and use the normal event loop via mainloop()
2. Get rid of the w.delete(ALL) and reuse the blocks (just move them around instead of delete and recreate them all)
3. Use the help of the canvas find() method to do collision detection instead of your check only in python code
4. Rewrite in Tcl so you can use Tcl's threading instead of the crippled CPython threads (only useful if you have more than one CPU/core) ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You've likely hit the limits of Tk - its not designed for animation and other fancy footwork.

The best option would be an optimized library such as PyGame. There shouldn't be a reason it won't run on Win 7 64bit - just make sure you have a Python that matches the PyGame (likely 32bit Python).

Comment: There shouldn't be a reason PyGame doesn't run, but it fails to run nonetheless!  I tried 32-bit Python 2.6.6, and though pygame installs, none of the examples work!  For example, I get:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pygame\examples\chimp.py",   line 18, in <module>
    main_dir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined  
  
Why is this happening?
Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Actually, pygame does work with some examples I got online, but not with the examples (ex, chimp.py above) that came with the installation!  What could be happening?

Comment: Thats not a limitation of Tk, Tk can do some anim stuff just fine, just watch the demos or games on the Tcl'ers wiki. For example the links at: http://wiki.tcl.tk/898

Answer (score -1):

some minimal changes:

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *
from time import *

root = Tk()

w = Canvas(root, width = 640, height=640, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
w.pack()

entities = []
running = True

## Size of squares, in pixels
size = 5

## Make tiles a 128x128 array
tiles = []
for i in range(128):
    tiles.append(128*[0])


## IMPORTANT: all entities must have .x and .y attributes!

class Entity:

    def __init__(self):
        self.setup()
        entities.append(self)

    def setup(self, x=0,y=0, name='Undefined', color='pink'):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def checkCollsn(self, try_x , try_y):
        for i in entities:
            if i is not self and try_x == i.x and try_y == i.y:
                #print i.name, 'is in the way of', self.name, '!'
                return False
        else:
            ## print 'All clear!'
            return True


    def maintain(self):
        for i in entities:
            if i is not self:
                ## Detect anything in immediate proximity:
                dx = abs(i.x - self.x)
                dy = abs(i.y - self.y)
                if (dx == 1 or dx == 0) and (dy == 1 or dy== 0):
                    pass
                    #print self.name, 'has detected', i.name
                    ## TODO: Then what?

        ## TODO: Add other 'maintainance checks' here.


class Mobile(Entity):  ## Mobile is a subclass of Entity, which can move!  
    def up(self):
        if self.y < 1:
            self.y = 0
        else:
            if self.checkCollsn(self.x, self.y-1):
                self.y -= 1

    def down(self):
        if self.y > 127:
            self.y = 127
        else:
            if self.checkCollsn(self.x, self.y+1):
                self.y += 1

    def left(self):
        if self.x < 1:
            self.x = 0
        else:
            if self.checkCollsn(self.x-1, self.y):
                self.x -= 1

    def right(self):
        if self.x > 127:
            self.x = 127
        else:
            if self.checkCollsn(self.x+1, self.y):
                self.x += 1


def fractalGen(iterations=5, chanceWater=0.5):
    for i in range(iterations):
        if i == 0:
            ## Generate random 16x16 blocks
            blockNo = 8
            blockLen = 16
            randomize = True
            fractalize = False
        else:
            randomize = False
            fractalize = True

        if i == 1:
            blockNo = 16
            blockLen = 8

        if i == 2:
            blockNo = 32
            blockLen = 4

        if i == 3:
            blockNo = 64
            blockLen = 2

        if i == 4:
            blockNo = 128
            blockLen = 1

        if i > 4:
            print 'Excessive i value! Was', i

        for yBlock in range(blockNo):
            ## If it stays red, something's screwy!
            blockVal = 0

            for xBlock in range(blockNo):
                if randomize:
                    ## print 'i:',i,'Randomizing.'
                    r = random()
                    if r <= chanceWater:
                        blockVal = 4
                    else: blockVal = 3

                if fractalize:
                    land = 0
                    water = 0
                    ## First, assess surrounding % water of all valid surrounding blocks.
                    ## Remember, blocks are now higher res than previous iteration!


                    xRange = [0]  ## This paragraph makes sure we're staying within
                    yRange = [0]  ## the range of the matrix.

                    if xBlock != 0:
                        xRange.append(-1)
                    if xBlock != blockNo-1:
                        xRange.append(1)

                    if yBlock != 0:
                        yRange.append(-1)
                    if yBlock != blockNo-1:
                        yRange.append(1)                    


                    for ySign in yRange:
                        yCheck = (yBlock+ySign)*blockLen
                        for xSign in xRange:
                            xCheck = (xBlock+xSign)*blockLen
                            if xSign ==0 and ySign == 0:
                                selfVal = tiles[yCheck][xCheck]
                                ## print 'Self is', selfVal
                            else:
                                if tiles[yCheck][xCheck] == 4:
                                    ## print 'Water at', xCheck, yCheck
                                    water += 1
                                if tiles[yCheck][xCheck] == 3:
                                    land += 1
                                    ## print 'Land at', xCheck, yCheck
                    percentWater = water/float(land+water)
                    ##print percentWater
                    if selfVal == 4: #If self is water, oppSurr is % land
                        oppSurr = 1 - percentWater
                    if selfVal == 3: #If self is land, oppSurr is % water
                        oppSurr = percentWater

                    r = randint(0,25)/100.0
                    ##print oppSurr, r, oppSurr + r

                    if oppSurr + r >= 0.625:
                    ## If surroundings + random > 50%, switch self type!
                        if selfVal == 4:
                            blockVal = 3
                            ## print 'To land'
                        elif selfVal == 3:
                            blockVal = 4
                            ## print 'To water'
                    ## else: print 'Not switched, remains', selfVal
                    else: blockVal = selfVal


                    ## NB: Must assign blockVal in all cases, otherwise
                    ## you get the last value of blockVal carried over!

                for y in range(yBlock*blockLen,(yBlock+1)*blockLen):
                    for x in range(xBlock*blockLen,(xBlock+1)*blockLen):
                        tiles[y][x] = blockVal

def drawWorld():

    x=0
    y=0

    for i in tiles:
        for j in i:
            color = 'gray'
            if j == 0: tColor = 'red'
            if j == 1: tColor = 'orange'
            if j == 2: tColor = 'yellow'
            if j == 3: tColor = 'green'
            if j == 4: tColor = 'blue'
            if j == 5: tColor = 'purple'

            w.create_rectangle(x,y,x+size,y+size,fill=tColor)
            x += size

        x = 0
        y += size
    w.update()

def draw_entities():
    w.delete('ent')
    for i in entities:
        w.create_rectangle(i.x*size, i.y*size, i.x*size+size, i.y*size+size, fill=i.color, tags='ent')

def moveRand(ent):
    cmd = randint(0,3) 
    if cmd == 0: ent.up()
    if cmd == 1: ent.down()
    if cmd == 2: ent.left()
    if cmd == 3: ent.right()

def keyPress(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        p.up()

    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        p.down()

    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        p.left()

    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        p.right()

fractalGen(5,.4)
drawWorld()

## Player:
p = Mobile()
p.setup(0,5,'Man', 'white')

## Boulder:
b = Entity()
b.setup(10,15,'Boulder','black')

## Flower:
f = Entity()
f.setup(5,5,'Flower', 'red')

## Elf:
elf = Mobile()
elf.setup(10,10,'Elf','pink')

##interval = 0.2 #?

draw_entities()

root.bind_all('<Key>', keyPress)

try:
    while running:
        moveRand(elf)
        for i in entities:
            i.maintain()
        draw_entities()
        w.update()
except TclError:
    pass
```